# SQL statement for trial balance to display from table with one column of debit minus credit amount

Tags: sql, firebird

I need trial balance from following tables:

Table: Journal

| ID | TransactionDate | AccountCodeLevel1VarChar | AccountCodeLevel2VarChar | AccountCodeLevel3VarChar | AccountCodeLevel4VarChar | AccountCodeLevel5VarChar | AccountCodeLevel6VarChar | DebitAmountDecimal | CreditAmountDecimal | DescriptionVarchar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-1-1 | 1 | 01 | 01 | 01 | 001 | 001 | 1 |  | Received cash from issuing common stocks |
| 2 | 2022-1-1 | 3 | 01 | 01 | 01 | 001 | 001 |  | 1 | Received cash from issuing common stocks |
| 3 | 2022-1-1 | 1 | 01 | 01 | 01 | 001 | 001 | 2 |  | Received cash borrowed from bank |
| 4 | 2022-1-1 | 2 | 01 | 01 | 01 | 001 | 001 |  | 2 | Received cash borrowed from bank |
| 5 | 2022-1-1 | 1 | 01 | 01 | 01 | 001 | 001 | 3 |  | Received cash borrowed from bank |
| 6 | 2022-1-1 | 2 | 01 | 01 | 01 | 001 | 001 |  | 3 | Received cash borrowed from bank |
| 7 | 2022-1-1 | 1 | 01 | 01 | 01 | 001 | 001 | 4 |  | Received cash from selling products |
| 8 | 2022-1-1 | 4 | 01 | 01 | 01 | 001 | 001 |  | 4 | Received cash from selling products |
| 9 | 2022-1-1 | 1 | 01 | 01 | 01 | 001 | 001 | 5 |  | Collected cash from services rendered |
| 10 | 2022-1-1 | 4 | 02 | 01 | 01 | 001 | 001 |  | 5 | Collected cash from services rendered |
| 11 | 2022-1-1 | 5 | 01 | 01 | 01 | 001 | 001 | 6 |  | Paid employee salaries |
| 12 | 2022-1-1 | 1 | 01 | 01 | 01 | 001 | 001 |  | 6 | Paid employee salaries |

Table: AccountCode

| AccountCodeLevel1VarChar | AccountCodeLevel2VarChar | AccountCodeLevel3VarChar | AccountCodeLevel4VarChar | AccountCodeLevel5VarChar | AccountCodeLevel6VarChar | AccountNameVarChar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01 | 01 | 01 | 001 | 001 | Cash |
| 2 | 01 | 01 | 01 | 001 | 001 | Loan from banks |
| 3 | 01 | 01 | 01 | 001 | 001 | Paid-up common shares |
| 4 | 01 | 01 | 01 | 001 | 001 | Service revenue |
| 4 | 02 | 01 | 01 | 001 | 001 | Sales revenue |
| 5 | 01 | 01 | 01 | 001 | 001 | Salary |

How can I get the SQL to render the summary result as shown hereunder with DebitAmountDecimal minus CreditAmountDecimal?

| AccountCodeLevel1VarChar | AccountCodeLevel2VarChar | AccountCodeLevel3VarChar | AccountCodeLevel4VarChar | AccountCodeLevel5VarChar | AccountCodeLevel6VarChar | AccountNameVarChar | TrialBalanceAmount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01 | 01 | 01 | 001 | 001 | Cash | 9 |
| 2 | 01 | 01 | 01 | 001 | 001 | Loan from banks | -5 |
| 3 | 01 | 01 | 01 | 001 | 001 | Paid-up common shares | -1 |
| 4 | 01 | 01 | 01 | 001 | 001 | Service revenue | -4 |
| 4 | 02 | 01 | 01 | 001 | 001 | Sales revenue | -5 |
| 5 | 01 | 01 | 01 | 001 | 001 | Salary | 6 |

I tried to do with this SQL statement but the result is wrong:

```
SELECT 
"ACC"."AccountCodeLevel1VarChar", 
"ACC"."AccountCodeLevel2VarChar", 
"ACC"."AccountCodeLevel3VarChar", 
"ACC"."AccountCodeLevel4VarChar", 
"ACC"."AccountCodeLevel5VarChar", 
"ACC"."AccountCodeLevel6VarChar", 
"ACC"."AccountNameVarChar", 
SUM( "JNL"."DebitAmountDecimal" - "JNL"."CreditAmountDecimal" ) "TrialBalanceAmount" 
FROM 
"AccountCode" "ACC", "Journal" "JNL" 
WHERE 
"ACC"."AccountCodeLevel1VarChar" = "JNL"."AccountCodeLevel1VarChar" 
AND 
"ACC"."AccountCodeLevel2VarChar" = "JNL"."AccountCodeLevel2VarChar" 
AND 
"ACC"."AccountCodeLevel3VarChar" = "JNL"."AccountCodeLevel3VarChar" 
AND 
"ACC"."AccountCodeLevel4VarChar" = "JNL"."AccountCodeLevel4VarChar" 
AND 
"ACC"."AccountCodeLevel5VarChar" = "JNL"."AccountCodeLevel5VarChar" 
AND 
"ACC"."AccountCodeLevel6VarChar" = "JNL"."AccountCodeLevel6VarChar" 
GROUP BY 
"ACC"."AccountCodeLevel1VarChar", 
"ACC"."AccountCodeLevel2VarChar", 
"ACC"."AccountCodeLevel3VarChar", 
"ACC"."AccountCodeLevel4VarChar", 
"ACC"."AccountCodeLevel5VarChar", 
"ACC"."AccountCodeLevel6VarChar", 
"ACC"."AccountNameVarChar" 
ORDER BY 
"ACC"."AccountCodeLevel1VarChar" ASC, 
"ACC"."AccountCodeLevel2VarChar" ASC, 
"ACC"."AccountCodeLevel3VarChar" ASC, 
"ACC"."AccountCodeLevel4VarChar" ASC, 
"ACC"."AccountCodeLevel5VarChar" ASC, 
"ACC"."AccountCodeLevel6VarChar" ASC
```

Comment: Please provide a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_4.0), and simplify your example, a lot of those columns are entirely unnecessary for asking your question, and only make it harder to read. Are the debit/credit columns `NULL` if there is no value? If so, you need to use `SUM("JNL"."DebitAmountDecimal") - SUM("JNL"."CreditAmountDecimal")`, otherwise you're just summing NULL.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by “the result is wrong”? What result are you getting and how is it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much @Mark Rotteveel for the comment that I was summing `NULL`.

```
SUM( COALESCE ( "JNL"."DebitAmountDecimal", 0 ) ) - SUM( COALESCE ( "JNL"."CreditAmountDecimal", 0 ) ) "TrialBalanceAmount"
```

Now the result is complete.

Comment: The coalesce shouldn't be necessary if you SUM the columns individually. The original problem was you had `SUM(column1 - column2)`, which, as either column1 was null or column2 was null in a row, resulted in `NULL - non-null -> NULL` or `non-null - NULL -> NULL` being summed, but if you sum columns individually, that is not problem (SUM ignores NULLs).